# Can an HttpModule invoke a new IE pop-up window?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, popup, httpmodule

I am developing a custom application feedback tool.  The idea is that when the user launches a particular application, I want a pop-up to appear, say a couple seconds after the user launches the application, that asks if they'd be willing to provide feedback.  The pop-up will simply be a new IE window.  So, something similar in functionality to:

```
Response.Write("<script>window.open('" + sUrl + "', 'mywindow','resizable= yes,scrollbars= yes');</script>");
```

We have numerous web apps (ASP.NET) in our company, and I think the quickest solution would be to drop an `HttpModule` into the application's solution.  For an ideal example, see: http://www.foreseeresults.com/.

**QUESTION**: Is invoking a new internet browser pop-up possible with an `HttpModule`?  Or is perhaps invoking JavaScript from an `HttpModule` possible on the client's browser?

Comment: Will your users not have their popup blocker enabled?

Comment: That's an option.  Let's assume they won't have their pop-up blocker enabled..

Comment: Or even, invoking client side JavaScript from the HttpModule.. that might be an option as well if it's possible?

Comment: You'd have to make sure the response isn't being redirected, and is returning HTML rather than script, css, images or embedded resources. It would probably be easier and safer to add the code to the master page for each site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using ASP.NET HTTP Response Filters.

You implement your custom filter and then set it inside a custom `HttpModule` or inside a Global.asax file by handling the `PostReleaseRequestState` event.

Bellow is an article by Scott Mitchel on HTTP Response Filters.

https://web.archive.org/web/20211029043851/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120308-1.aspx

This article contains two simple response filters, which should give you the right direction on how to implement your case. I suggest you to display a modal dialog using jQuery and display a message. When user confirms that dialog open a new web page in new window (this way you'll also get around popup blockers).

Hope this helps!

Regards,
Uros

Comment: They use VB... I don't like VB, haha.  I need to find an example that's C#

Comment: Hi, you have examples in both languages, scroll to the bottom of page and download article source code