# Can an HttpModule invoke client-side Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, popup, httpmodule

I am developing a custom application feedback tool, and I want a JavaScript popup to appear when the user visits a web application that asks if they'd be willing to provide feedback, similar to the pop-up you get here: http://www.foreseeresults.com/, when you first visit it.

Is invoking client side JavaScript possible with an `HttpModule`?  The reason I want/need to use an `HttpModule` is because I need to be able to drop this in every one of our applications in our company.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between client-side and server-side code.  You can inject Javascript into responses.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333391/can-an-httpmodule-invoke-a-new-ie-pop-up-window/20335208#20335208

Comment: @UrošGoljat Yes, that's my post as well.  Different question though- Javascript versus server side code.

Comment: In both ways you'll need some kind of mechanism to inject HTML/JavaScript into response to implement this. I think that creating a HTTP Response Filter is a very elegant solution to your problem.